# Error 'No bounding' box for PDF image

Tags: graphics, hyperref, bounding-box

I have a LaTeX file which includes a PDF image file as follows

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{chapter1/figure/image.pdf}
\caption{...}
\label{aa:b}
\end{figure}
```

I can compile this without any problems using `pdflatex`. But when I include the package `hyperref` and a bunch of other packages, it gives me the following error:

```
File 'chapter1/figure/image.bb' not found. ...dth]{chapter1/figure/image.pdf}
Cannot determine the size of graphic in chapter1/figure/image.bb (no BoundingBox). ...dth]{chapter1/figure/image.pdf}
```

Comment: This may be a very localized problem. Could you post the PDF image somewhere so that users can have access to it? It would also be preferable to supply an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) required to reproduce the problem. For example, would using `graphicx` and `hyperref` in the `article document class be sufficient to reproduce your problem (given the image/PDF)?

Comment: I am using the template found in here [link](https://etd.helpdesk.ufl.edu/download.php) with the necessary package driver modifications. since there are many files in the template, I am not sure how to post a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely calling [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) with a specific driver option not compatible with the compiler/graphics format. For example

```
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
```

Remove this option and let `graphicx` do its own thing of figuring out the required graphics driver.

Alternatively, if all else fails, you could also try supplying the correct bounding box as option:

```
\includegraphics[bb=llx lly urx ury]{image}
```

where `llx lly urx ury` denotes the `l`ower-`l`eft (`x`,`y`) and `u`pper-`r`ight (`x`,`y`) coordinate of the image in `bp`s (big points).

Comment: Already tried the package driver option with no success. Also, I just tried supplying bounding box manually, which also did not work.All of the files and figures had no problems with any other template (oxford university press templates, for example)

Comment: @gunan: This should not be a template problem, but rather something to do with *either* your TeX distribution, or the image itself. Do the following: (1) Post your entire preamble (including document class) as an [edit to your original post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/44808/edit) and (2) include what is posted *after* `**File List**` in your `.log` file after you add `\listfiles` *before* `\documentclass`; (3) perhaps upload a problem image somewhere and post a link to it. Without any of this information, it would be hard to assess what the problem is.

Comment: In my case it was necessary to comment-out the whole line "\usepackage{graphicx}"

Comment: I have the same problem, but `graphicx` is not included in any of my style files. I guess it's nested way down? Is there any way to un-include it?

Comment: @mohawkjohn: Sometimes you load a package that loads [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) as a dependency since it does form part of the "required" packages. If you add `\listfiles` to your document preamble, you'll see a `**File List**` in your `.log`, from which you can trace the dependencies of packages/files loaded by corroborating the list with the loading order in your own preamble. Anything that is not listed in the preamble is loaded as a dependency of another package.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page when encountering a similar problem.  I didn't have graphicx explicitly loaded, but I was including epsfig.  When I moved the usepackage{hyperref} *below* epsfig, everything worked as expected.